# How to cancel progress dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

Am using ProgressDialog(SPINNER) in webview to load pages, but i want the dialog to have a cancel button so that when user clicks the button the progress dialog should stop loading.
I have tried the cancel button but the progress dialog do not cancel it goes and comes back.

All i want to do is cancel the dialog that is all

Thank you

Comment: Did you call `progressdialog.cancel()` ?

Comment: yeah i tried progressdialog.cancel() but it still returns

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

or also you can try this.

```
myDialog = new ProgressDialog(BaseScreen.this);
myDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
myDialog.setCancelable(false);
myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
myDialog.show();
```

all credit goes to SO only, i just find content and got this answer. So hope this gonna help you.

Comment: yeah i tried this code and it did not work, the progress dialog still comes back